# Apache Server does not server any websites other than the default one

Tags: apache2, webserver, apache2.4

Hi I'm new to Apache and trying to learn how to host multiple websites.

I've 2 domains `www.daily-updates.ga` & `www.prudent-solutions.co.in` and a VPS server with ubuntu 18.04 and Apache2 installed. I'm able to see the Apache's default page when I go to my server's IP from other PC.

As a next step I created 2 test websites and 2 directories in `/var/www`. I also copied the default config file and changed the `ServerName, ServerAlias, DocumentRoot` for both the webstites.

**daily-updates.ga.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName daily-updates.ga
        ServerAlias www.daily-updates.ga
        DocumentRoot /var/www/daily-updates.ga/


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**prudent-solutions.co.in :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName prudent-solutions.co.in
        ServerAlias www.prudent-solutions.co.in

        DocumentRoot /var/www/prudent-solutions.co.in/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf

```
# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf.d
#   |   `-- *

# Global configuration
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 30
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 300
KeepAliveTimeout 10

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          8
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      20
    ServerLimit         256
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75 
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          200
    MaxRequestsPerChild 4000
</IfModule>

# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
#User www-data
#Group www-data

AccessFileName .htaccess

<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>

DefaultType None
HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
Include ports.conf

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
LogFormat "%b" bytes

Include conf.d/

# Include the virtual host configurations:
#Include sites-enabled/

ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 501 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 502 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 503 /error/50x.html
ErrorDocument 506 /error/50x.html


<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied  
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/prudent-solutions.co.in>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I then enabled those by the `a2ensite` command

I'm pretty sure that my DNS records are perfect and are pointed to my server's IP address. However, when I go to `www.daily-updates.ga` or `www.prudent-solutions.co.in` I still see only the Apache2 default page

Screen Shot `www.prudent-solutions.co.in`:
[Screenshot of the default page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDLKv.png)

Similarly, when I go to `www.daily-updates.ga` I get the same page.

What Am I doing wrong? Why Am I not able to see the correct website? I know my there is an error in conf file but can't figure it out

Please Help !!!

Comment: I recommend moving the <Directory> block for each vhost into it's corresponding file in conf.d. Then set `LogLevel debug`, restart apache, and watch your log/error files.

Comment: That works!!! Thank you so much. Actually I upgraded the Ubuntu OS to 20.04 from 18.04. And somehow that seem to work perfectly now.